# Joomla template module override not working for mobile template

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I try to explain this properly, its a bit confusing.

Scenario:

My Joomla has a desktop template and a mobile template. It is suppose to switch template according to the device use to view the site.

My Issue:

The switching of template works well but when viewing mobile site, Joomla template override does not get the correct module override from the mobile template. It gets the module override from the desktop template.

I did a test by adding this code

```
echo JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_mymodule')
```

in my mobile template index.php to check which override folder it is using for a particular module and it shows

```
.../desktop_template/html/mod_mymodule/default.php
```

this is not correct and it should actually be

```
.../mobile_template/html/mod_mymodule/default.php
```

I am not sure why it is not using my mobile template path since the viewport is showing my mobile template. This happen to all my module which has overrides. It seem like it cannot detect mobile template override files.

My Question is:

Is there a way that i can manually change JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_mymodule') to my mobile path in my mobile template index.php

Or

Is there a way to manipulate jdoc:include in mobile template to use override files in my mobile template.

Answer (score 0):

ok first of all two different templates is not a good way i think. You dont need for a mobile switch two templates. I would do it with layouts. So you could send a optionally layout path for your module like:

```
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_xyz', 'newlayout'));
```

Cos joomla uses the template that is assigned to the menu item (i guess desktop).

Maybe its a way to use two templates, but i think its very strange.